# Flex AS3 DNS lookup

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, dns

Can a DNS lookup be made with AS3?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe it _is_ possible in flash, but just not in the way you are thinking right now.

Comment: I need to have flash to a SRV lookup for a hostname in order to get the host and port for a service. In this case XMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly - you will have to call a serverside script (php/jsp/asp/cgi/...) that does the lookup for you and returns the data, and most probably that script will have to do a command line call.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So AS3 has no DNS library built in? Has anyone tried developing one? AS3 has TCP and UDP support, so I don't see why there isn't any DNS query library. ie: I'm hoping I don't have to resort to a server-side script.

Comment: Networking is limited in flash, mostly for security (sandbox), but also because it is living 'inside' the browser (at least if you are using flash like it is mostly used). This means most of the time you cannot connect to a server that does not explicitely allow it, that probably rules out most of your options.

Comment: right. somehow I forgot about that. However, if I set up a set of nameservers, and allow access to all, flash should be able to query it. Now I'm just wondering if anyone has done DNS in flash before? or if I have to write a webservice to do the job..

Answer (score 5):

I know this is kind of an older question and it may be too late, and if I could I'd add this as a comment... but in case it helps someone, there is apparently an implementation of some sort in AIR:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/dns/DNSResolver.html

This may help bucabay in writing their custom one... but it is not a full answer to the original question since it is not available in the flash player, just AIR- but it is still technically AS3.